# CSS - element custom radius?

Tags: css

I am trying to add a custom border radius like this hero image: https://www.magicleap.com/magic-leap-one

I am aware that it's the image that does that, my question is can I do something like that using CSS?

Comment: You will need to use an image-based solution for that (eg SVG), pure CSS-alone wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: Your reference site isn't border-radius it's an image. You can create an SVG image or PNG image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Hope this is what you're looking for.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), url(https://s1.kkday.com/images/product/8163/20170301045421_Nkoag.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 150px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 15%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100% 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>
    Hello World!
  </h1>
</div>
```